# Bootstrap css : very small text on my smartphone. Why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my very simple code. Normally, bootstrap css is mobile first. But when i open this file on Google Chrome in Android or via Google Chrome desktop with device mode, the text is very small and the page is zoomable.

How to avoid this behaviour ? I thought it was automatic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just understood that this behaviour is not in css, but directly in the page, with this code in `<head>` section, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

RTFM http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: You should accept this anwser so others know the issue is resolved

Comment: It's myself that have found the answer so i can accept it only in two days. Perhaps you can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Bootstrap Template Code First :

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```